# What "en..., a... de... de... yo" means in Spanish application form?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, preposiciones, redacción

I've got an application form in Spanish, which starts with

> En.................., a.... de.... de .........
>
> Yo,............................................
>
> (Profesion u oficio).........domiciliado en....

Looks like I am supposed to write name and surname after `Yo,` but what the first line means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Location and date you are filling the form, like:

> En ***Madrid***, a ***27*** de ***febrero*** de ***2018***
>
> Yo, ***Full Name***,
>
> ***occupation***, domiciliado en ***full address***

Answer (score 5):

That's for writing the date. If you were filling that form today in, say, Barcelona, it would look like this:

> **En** *Barcelona*, **a** *27* **de** *febrero* **de** *2018*.

Remember: dates in Spanish are day, month, year; and month names are lowercase.

Comment: Unless you use roman numerals for the month, in which case uppercase is preferred :-)

Comment: Touché (although sometimes I do feel like I'm the only person that still writes dates using them)